# SQL combining two records into one

Tags: mysql

I want to combine the following two records into one record.

```
PCNUMMER EZONE1  EDATUM1     EZONE2
10581    E       2013-06-03  A
10581    B       2013-11-14  NULL
10987    A       2013-11-11  NULL
```

What I want to have is

```
PCNUMMER EZONE1  EDATUM1     EZONE2
10581    B       2013-06-03  A
10987    A       2013-11-11  NULL
```

because the date of the records where EZONE1 = 'B' is after the date of the record where EZONE1 = 'E'. But when the data = 'NULL' then the data must be taken of the older record (if not NULL and if there is an older record)

So how I get this result?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Try using the having clause as it seems you want to use an "if" style statement in your where clause. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible way to do it, taking advantage that GROUP_CONCAT will ignore null values:-

```
SELECT PCNUMMER, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EZONE1 ORDER BY EDATUM1 DESC), ',', 1), MAX(EDATUM1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(EZONE2 ORDER BY EDATUM1 DESC), ',', 1)
FROM SomeTable 
GROUP BY PCNUMMER
```